# Fedora won't start after update

Tags: fedora, startup

About 1 month ago I installed the newest version of Fedora, so that I had both Windows and Fedora on one machine. Today I installed some software and some updates and rebooted the system, but unfortunately Fedora won't start anymore:

It just shows me the Fedora logo instead of the login screen [image: Fedora Logo]

Update: My graphic card is AMD Radeon™ HD 5000 Series.

Comment: If you have a live CD, I would boot to that and check the grub to make sure the boot-loader link isn't broken

Comment: Did you install the AMD Catalyst proprietary driver?  If so, do you know what version?  Do you know what kernel version you are using?  Run `uname -r` to check your kernel version.

Comment: Check for graphics-related errors by running `grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log` as root.

Answer (score 3):

You've not given out many clues in your question. However, there are a few options open to you:

First, boot and at the `grub` menu press a key to stop the boot.  Use the cursor keys to select the latest kernel and press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the entry.

Use the cursor keys again to select the entry that starts with `linux` and move to the end of the line.  Try some of the following (not necessarily all at the same time):

- Remove the `quiet` and `rhgb`.  This will allow you to see what's happening as it boots.
- Add the word `single` to the end and boot.  You should be able to log in as `root` and carry out some diagnostics.
- Add `selinux=0` to disable `SELinux` which can cause mayhem if it goes wrong.

Another useful technique is to boot as normal and when you get to the black screen, press <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to bring up a terminal.  If it works, you can log in and carry out some diagnostics.  The advantage of this is that you're at the normal run-level with `SELinux` enabled, which is nearer the usual running state of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Often when the OS boots but then shows a command prompt or a black screen instead of a GUI login, there is a problem with the graphics driver.  The most common cause of this is updating the kernel but not the driver's kernel module.  If this is the problem, a short-term work-around is to choose the previous kernel from the grub boot menu.

To solve the problem completely, we'll need to know more details about the problem.

Comment: In fact I have problems with my graphic driver with windows. Can it also cause problems with linux? Are they connected? Btw: My graphic card is AMD Radeon™ HD 5000 Series.

Comment: @user1170330 It's doubtful that the two are connected but the fact that you have an AMD graphics card is likely relevant to the problem.  You should edit your question to add that information.